# Making LinearModelFit account for Log on the x-axis

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following code that I wish to run, which consists of 6 data points that I want to fit using `LinearModelFit`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ϕ0 = 2.068*10^-15;(*femto-Tm^2*)
zchar = 50;
LLl1 = 500*10^-12(*H*);
LLl2 = 900*10^-12(*H*);
LLl3 = 1000*10^-12(*H*);
LLl4 = 1500*10^-12(*H*);
LLl5 = 1670*10^-12(*H*);
LLl6 = 2000*10^-12(*H*);
I01 = ϕ0/(2 π*LLl1);
I02 = ϕ0/(2 π*LLl2);
I03 = ϕ0/(2 π*LLl3);
I04 = ϕ0/(2 π*LLl4);
I05 = ϕ0/(2 π*LLl5);
I06 = ϕ0/(2 π*LLl6);

Il1 = 0.0257399*Sqrt[2]*(28.3346/26.26)*(0.5*I01)(*As/Ap*Sqrt[2]*(ωs/ωp)(0.5*I0) for 20.0227dB \gain*);
Il2 = 0.0257399*Sqrt[2]*(15.5602/14.43)*(0.5*I02)(*As/Ap*Sqrt[2]*(ωs/ωp)(0.5*I0) for 20.004dB \gain*);
Il3 = 0.0261556*Sqrt[2]*(13.985/12.97)*(0.5*I03)(*As/Ap*Sqrt[2]*(ωs/ωp)(0.5*I0) for 20.0038dB \gain*);
Il4 = 0.0257399*Sqrt[2]*(9.28253/8.61)*(0.5*I04)(*As/Ap*Sqrt[2]*(ωs/ωp)(0.5*I0) for 20.0358dB \gain*);
Il5 = 0.0257399*Sqrt[2]*(8.33335/7.73)*(0.5*I05)(*As/Ap*Sqrt[2]*(ωs/ωp)(0.5*I0) for 20.0318dB \gain*);
Il6 = 0.0261566*Sqrt[2]*(6.95093/6.448)*(0.5*I06)(*As/Ap*Sqrt[2]*(ωs/ωp)(0.5*I0) for 20.006dB \gain*);

pl1 = (Il1^2*zchar)/2*1000(*in milliWatts*);
pl2 = (Il2^2*zchar)/2*1000(*in milliWatts*);
pl3 = (Il3^2*zchar)/2*1000(*in milliWatts*);
pl4 = (Il4^2*zchar)/2*1000(*in milliWatts*);
pl5 = (Il5^2*zchar)/2*1000(*in milliWatts*);
pl6 = (Il6^2*zchar)/2*1000(*in milliWatts*);

pointsLHTL = {{I01, 10 Log10[pl1]}, {I02, 10 Log10[pl2]}, {I03, 
10 Log10[pl3]}, {I04, 10 Log10[pl4]}, {I05, 10 Log10[pl5]}, {I06, 10 Log10[pl6]}};


LHdynamicrange = 
ListLogLinearPlot[Evaluate@pointsLHTL, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotLegends -> {"LH"}, 
Joined -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue]]

Lm = LinearModelFit[Log@pointsLHTL, x, x]
Lmplot = Plot[Lm[x], {x, -16, -14}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed], PlotLegends -> {"Linear fit"}]

Show[Lmplot, LHdynamicrange]
```

where `pointsLHTL` represent my data points (with the y-values under `Log10` and multiplied by `10`). `LHdyanmicrange` is a `ListLogLinearPlot` of `pointsLHTL` as I want the x-axis to be under Log scale as well (natural in this case).

However, my fitting curve `Lm` and its plot `Lmplot` does not account for the Log values as shown in `LHdynamicrange`. How can I adjust my `Lmplot` or `Lm` so that it incorporates the Log scale similar to `LHdynamicrange` when I `Show` both of them on the same plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are evaluating `Log` on all elements of `pointsLHTL`, not just the `x` values. The `y` values are negative so the `Log` is imaginary.

```
Lm = LinearModelFit[pointsLHTL /. {x_, y_} :> {Log@x, y}, x, x]

Lmplot = 
 Plot[Lm[x], {x, -16, -14}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed], 
  PlotLegends -> {"Linear fit"}]

Show[Lmplot, LHdynamicrange]
```

[image]

Comment: I technically want the x-axis to be showing the pre-Log values but I can fix that by simply doing `Show[LHdynamicrange,Lmplot]` instead. Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @kowalski You are welcome. Thanks for the accept.